# Run bash command with $1, $2 in Python

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, arguments, popen

Hi I need to run following bash command in python:

```sh
function get_setting () {
   echo $(cat /proc/cmdline |
   awk -F"$1=" '{print $2}' | awk -F" " '{ print $1 }' )
}
```

I tried this:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(["cat", "/proc/cmdline | awk -F"$1=" '{print $2}' | awk -F" " '{ print $1 }", "BOOT_IMAGE"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

but it doesn't work.

I don't want to load bash script and run it by python.
How do I do that? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
thanks

Comment: Make sure to escape your double quotes: `...-F\"$1=\"...`

Comment: Don't abuse cat. Instead pass the file name to awk args. Also can you clarify "doesn't work"? What happens. What is your output?

Comment: This doesn't work in it's current form because the `|` pipelines are a shell feature and you are not using `shell=True`. IMO don't bother trying to subprocess this, you can trivially rewrite it in pure python since it's just basic string parsing

Comment: +1 for @jordanm remark about doing it in python. Although it doesn't answer the OP's original question I would second his suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ignore @jorganm suggestion to use pure python (And I would suggest going with pure Python), then this works on my machine:

```
>>> Popen("cat /proc/cmdline | awk -F\"$1=\" '{print $2}' | awk -F\" \" '{ print $1 }'", shell="True")
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x7f2cf1a12550>
>>> /vmlinuz-3.10.0-1160.2.2.el7.x86_64
```

Comment: Thanks, how do I pass arg?

Comment: Pass arg to what? You have three different commands that you are piping through.